# Unclear behavior when using async Kafka writer and RequiredAcks set to RequireNone in segmentio/kafka-go

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-kafka-go

When using [segmentio/kafka-go](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go)

It is unclear what is the difference in the behavior when writing with async mode and setting the RequiredAcks to different values: RequireNone, RequireOne, and RequireAll (0, 1, -1).

Specifically, let's have the following scenario:

- async Kafka writer, writing data in batches for multiple topics (topic is added to each message)
- callback function to handle the response
- required acks set to RequireNone
- number of replicas set to 3
- number of retries set to 10

Which responses will I get on my callback function:

1. If I don't get an error response can I assume the data successfully persisted
   on the leading broker?
2. will I get all the errors? or some errors I can get only when setting RequireOne?
3. will I get replica failures from the other brokers?
4. when I get an error response is it after it retried 10 times?
5. is there any advantage to setting the required acks to 1 if I don't
   care about the order?